# Etymology of Some Terms Used in Ratio and Proportion in Old Algebra Textbooks

Tags: mathematics, terminology, elementary-algebra

In older algebra textbooks for high school (mainly 19th century) four properties of ratio and proportions were used. The properties were Invertendo, Alternendo, Componendo, and Dividendo.  This terminology has vanished in most textbooks.

I could never locate these words in any *unabridged* English dictionaries (Oxford's multivolume dictionary, as well as Webster's). Most likely these are Latin words.

Does anyone know the literal meanings and English equivalents of these four words? Intuitively, they make sense but what is the word form (verb, adjective, noun?).
https://brilliant.org/wiki/componendo-and-dividendo/

Thanks.

Comment: They are Latin words. My Latin is very rusty, but the "-nd-" indicates a gerund, and the suffix "-o" probably indicates the ablative. So "invertendo" would be something like "by inverting", which makes sense since this says that if $a : b = c : d$ then $b : a = d : c$. By the same token "alternendo" means "by alternating" or "by arranging in alternate order": if $a : b = c : d$, then $a : c = b : d$

Comment: Checking my Oxford Latin Dictionary, one of the senses of *componere* is "to add together", so *componendo* would be "by adding together": if $a : b = c : d$ then $(a + b) : b = (c + d) : d$

Comment: The dictionary says *dividere* means to divide up, to separate into parts. I have no idea why that was considered descriptive of the math: if $a : b = c : d$ then $(a – b) : b = (c – d) : d$.

Comment: Someone in google forums had written that "These words are ablative cases of gerunds belonging to the verbs <alternare>, <componere>, <dividere>, and <invertere>. Since they are formed and used regularly, there is no reason to list them in dictionaries." Do you agree?

Comment: I agree that this is the correct list of Latin verbs these terms are based on. And the information on gerund and ablative matches with what I vaguely remember from Latin classes more than 35 years ago. I have no insights into lexicographical conventions regarding the addition of words to dictionaries.

Comment: @njuffa You should write this as an answer.

Comment: @Conifold Thanks for the encouragement. I have been pondering it for the past hour. Initially I did not want to write an answer because of my shaky command of Latin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These terms derive from the four Latin verbs *invertere* "to turn upside down", *alternare* "to alternate, to arrange in alternating order", *componere* "to add together", and *dividere* "to divide up, to separate into parts". The specific grammatical form is the [gerund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund), indicated by *-nd-*, and the grammatical case used is the [ablative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ablative_case), indicated by the suffix *-o*.

Therefore their literal meaning is: *invertendo* "by turning upside down" or "by inverting", *alternando* "by alternating" or "by arranging in alternate order", *componendo* "by adding together", and *dividendo* "by separating". Except for the final term, they clearly describe the underlying mathematical relationship:

*invertendo*: if $a : b = c : d$, then (by inverting) $b : a = d : c$
*alternando*: if $a : b = c : d$, then (by arranging in alternate order) $ a  :c=b:d$
*componendo*: if $a : b = c : d$, then (by adding together) $(a+b) : b = (c+d):d$
*dividendo*: if $a : b = c : d$, then (by separating) $(a - b ) :b = (c-d):d$

Comment: To separate (*dividere*) is the opposite of to put together (*componere*), but here I think it is not in the way that we think of addition and subtraction as opposites, at least not exactly. I think in *dividendo*, the sense is of separating $a$ into two quantities $a-b$ and $b$ and likewise for $c$.